# What decides to deallocate a local allocation on return?

Tags: c++, variables, memory-management, scope

So, I have 2 pieces of code, one that works and one that doesn't. The first piece was just a test to find out if a char pointer would remain valid after it is returned from a local allocation. For some reason this works:

```
    char* test(){
        char* rawr="what";
        return rawr;  
    }
```

But this one doesn't work:

```
    char* folderfromfile(char* filz) //gets the folder path from the file path
    {
            //declarations
            int  lastslash=-1;
            int  i        =0;
            char rett[256];

        for(i;(int)filz[i]!=0;i++)
                if(filz[i]=='\\')
                    lastslash=i;     //records the last known backslash

        if(lastslash==-1)
                return "";           //didn't find a backslash

        for(i=0;i<=lastslash;i++)
                rett[i]=filz[i];     // copies to new string

        rett[i]    =0; //end of string
        cout << &rett << "====" << rett << endl;

        system("pause>nul");//pause so i can watch over the memory before it deallocates
        return rett;  
    }
```

I bet that there is a better way to accomplish this task of removing the file name from the full path but for now I'm just trying to figure out why this char pointer gets deleted while the other one doesn't. If I had to guess I would say its because I declared it differently, or because its larger. Yes, I could just pass another char pointer as an argument to this function, but that wouldn't answer my question.

Comment: The first one *happens to work* because `"what"` happens to be located outside the stack by the compiler. Using a non-constant string, or perhaps just changing compiler, architecture or compiler flags, could change that. Don't even think of writting such broken code.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should really write one statement per line. Not only it would improve readability greatly, but also will make debugging much easier, especially when it comes to breakpoints.

Comment: That was some of the most ugly code I have seen. White space is your friend. People are going to be more willing to help you if the code is easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char* test(){
    char* rawr="what";
    return rawr;  
}
```

The string literal `"what"` is *not* allocated on the stack - it remains valid throughout the life of the program. However it must NOT be modified. The pointer `rawr` itself is on the stack, but this is only a problem if you write things like `&rawr`, getting a pointer-to-a-pointer.

```
char* folderfromfile(char* filz){ //gets the folder path from the file path
    int lastslash=-1,i=0;char rett[256]; //declarations
    ///// ...
    return rett;  
}
```

This, however, puts an *array* on the stack. `rett` here is implicitly `&rett[0]`, that is, gets a pointer to the first element of the array, which is very much on the stack, and is invalid after returning.

Answer (score 5):

rett is allocated on the stack so when the method returns it's memory space is no longer valid.

rawr points to a literal which your compiler likely reserves in (read-only) memory when the program runs.

Both approaches are wrong.

You need to allocate the buffer using new (or malloc in C) or use std::string.